# ORA-00942 error is generating while creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ddl

I have created a new view named CONS_INTERRUPTED_DATA for the main user hfdora and the view has been created successfully. But when I am trying to create the same view for another user (cis) of the same database after giving all the privileges to the user (cis) I am getting the below error,

**oms_consumer*

ERROR at line 13:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Both the user hfdora and cis are the part of same database and **this oms_consumer table is present at the database**

I have granted the following privileges for the user cis before creating the view

```
grant select on energization_info to cis;
grant select on trigger_info to cis;
grant select on oms_source to cis;
grant select on oms_consumer to cis;
grant connect,resource,dba to cis;

My sql query to create the view,

>CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CONS_INTERRUPTED_DATA AS
    SELECT
        trigger_info_A.b1 AS FDR_RMU_OFF_B1, trigger_info_A.b2 AS FDR_RMU_OFF_B2,
        trigger_info_A.B3TEXT AS FDR_RMU_OFF_B3TEXT, trigger_info_A.elem AS FDR_RMU_OFF_ELEM,
        trigger_info_B.b1 AS FDR_RMU_RESTORE_B1, trigger_info_B.b2 AS FDR_RMU_RESTORE_B2,
        trigger_info_B.B3TEXT AS FDR_RMU_RESTORE_B3TEXT,
        trigger_info_B.elem AS FDR_RMU_RESTORE_ELEM,
        oms_consumer.consumer_code, energization_info.b1 AS AFFECTED_B1,
        energization_info.b2 AS AFFECTED_B2, energization_info.b3text AS AFFECTED_B3TEXT,
        to_char(energization_info.deenergized_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY Hh24:MI:SS') AS DEENERGIZED_DATE,
        to_char(energization_info.energized_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY Hh24:MI:SS') AS ENERGIZED_DATE,
        trigger_info_A.comments AS KEY
    FROM
        energization_info, 
        trigger_info trigger_info_A,
        trigger_info trigger_info_B, 
        oms_consumer
    WHERE
        (energization_info.trigger_number = trigger_info_A.trigger_number)
        AND (energization_info.ENERGIZED_TRIGGER_NUMBER = trigger_info_B.trigger_number)
        AND (energization_info.b1 = oms_consumer.B1NAME 
             AND energization_info.b2 = oms_consumer.B2NAME 
             AND energization_info.b3 = oms_consumer.B3NAME)
    WITH READ ONLY;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue has been resolved. :-)

I have made the following changes,

```
FROM
        hfdora.energization_info, 
        hfdora.trigger_info trigger_info_A,
        hfdora.trigger_info trigger_info_B, 
        hfdora.oms_consumer
```

Now the same view is created for the user cis.

Answer (score 2):

The first step in diagnosing a problem when creating a view is to try the `select` part on its own. In this case you would still get the ORA-00942 error, but the problem is now just a query and access issue and not to do with the view specifically.

When you get *ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*, it's because either:

1. **The table or view name that you typed really doesn't exist.**

   - Check the spelling - maybe there is a typo.
   - Are you connected to a database where it exists? Perhaps you are on a test system that doesn't have it.
   - Query `dba_objects` to see whether the table exists in another schema. (If you don't have privileges to query dba_objects, `all_objects` lists everything you have permission to view, which may be some help.)
2. **It really does exist, but it's in another schema.**
   In that case, there are two possible issues:

   - You don't have permission to query it. The table's owner needs to `grant read on xyz` (substitute the actual table name for `xyz`) to either

     - you
     - `public` (if you want everyone to be able to see the data, not always advisable)
     - a [role](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-ROLE.html) that you have (but roles aren't used by stored PL/SQL or [views](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html), though, so it's possible that you can query a table in another schema thanks to a role that you have, but still not be able to create a view or a procedure that uses it.)
   - You need to specify the schema. Say you want to query the `REGIONS` table in `HR` but you are connected as `SCOTT`. If you just `select * from regions` it will look for `SCOTT.REGIONS`, which doesn't exist. To fix that, do one of the following:

     - use `hr.regions` explicitly in your query.
     - in your schema, `create or replace synonym regions for hr.regions;`
       Now whenever you refer to `regions`, the database will automatically redirect to `hr.regions`.
     - in any schema with permission to create public synonyms:
       `create or replace public synonym regions for hr.regions;`
       Now everyone connecting to the database will have any references to `regions` redirected to `hr.regions`, which isn't always a good idea, but it's one option anyway.
     - `alter session set current_schema = hr;`
       Now the default schema for resolving names of objects is `HR` and not the one you logged into. For applications that always log in as a different user than the one that owns the tables, you can create an [after logon trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html) so this is always set. Then they can just refer to `regions` etc without needing to specify any schema and without any synonyms.